# How to create a scope for an intermediate table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, models

I have 2 tables, `:photos`, `:albums`, and a matching table between the 2 called `:photo_listings`.

I want to show only the albums that have photos inside, so, I created a scope in the albums model:

```
scope :with_photos, -> {includes(:photos)}
```

The problem is that `:photos` is not directly a column for `:albums`, because photos and albums are
matched through `:photo_listings`. So, how can I make a scope for albums that lists only albums with assigned photos?

**Photo_listings Model**

```
class PhotoListing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

**Album Model**

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photo_listings
end
```

**Photo Model**

```
  has_many :photo_listings
  has_many :albums, :through => :photo_listings
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your `Album`

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photo_listings
  has_many :photos, through: :photo_listings # this line
end
```

then your scope should work. You just missed the `photos` relation on your `Album` model.